# Changing Bootstrap card text on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm working on a website where I have a list of products (displayed in bootstrap cards) I want to be able to change the card text when the user hovers over it to completely different text (Hide or replace the original text). Does anyone know of any elegant solutions or any pointers?
Thanks.

Comment: You could use CSS [`::before`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) and [`::after`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp) pseudo classes.

Comment: Hiya aLink. It is generally expected that you include any code you are trying and then other people can help edit it for you. Take a look here for some good tips. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make 2 divs containing the text and the text hover and toggle the display property depending of the card hover

```css
.card-hover-text{
    display:none;
}
.card:hover .card-text{
    display:none;
}
.card:hover .card-hover-text{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20width%3D%22286%22%20height%3D%22180%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20286%20180%22%20preserveAspectRatio%3D%22none%22%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22text%2Fcss%22%3E%23holder_180284fd0bb%20text%20%7B%20fill%3Argba(255%2C255%2C255%2C.75)%3Bfont-weight%3Anormal%3Bfont-family%3AHelvetica%2C%20monospace%3Bfont-size%3A14pt%20%7D%20%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg%20id%3D%22holder_180284fd0bb%22%3E%3Crect%20width%3D%22286%22%20height%3D%22180%22%20fill%3D%22%23777%22%3E%3C%2Frect%3E%3Cg%3E%3Ctext%20x%3D%22107.1953125%22%20y%3D%2296.3%22%3E286x180%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <p class="card-hover-text">New text</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```